# How can I add a section like in helm-find files to helm-mini

Tags: helm, helm-for-files

How can I get a section to helm-mini which just behaves if I invoke `helm-find-files`?

Adding `helm-source-files-in-current-dir` does almost what I want, but doesn't allow me to navigate to subdirectories (it rather opens then a dired buffer). Adding `helm-source-findutils` doesn't seem to have an effect (at least there is not a section added).

Here is a minimal `.emacs` file to show what I tried:

```
;; -*-Emacs-Lisp-*-
;; -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

(require 'package)

(package-initialize)

(setq inhibit-splash-screen 1)

(require 'helm)  

(require 'recentf) 

(helm-mode 1)
(recentf-mode 1)


(setq helm-mini-default-sources '(
                  ;helm-source-findutils
                  helm-source-files-in-current-dir
                  helm-source-recentf
                  ))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full behavior of `helm-find-files` is coming from `helm-source-find-files`. However, this variable has a docstring that says: "Should not be used among other sources."

A couple of observations, from trying a few things and looking at `helm-files.el`:

- Adding `helm-source-find-files` to `helm-mini-default-sources` does produce the desired effect, with the following caveat:
- The `helm-source-find-files` variable is initially `nil`, and it gets initialised only after `helm-find-files` has been invoked already at least once.

Based on all that, my take is:

- You can make it work, by taking `helm-source-find-files` as a basis, but you will have to initialise it - meaning digging through `helm-files.el` and figuring how to do it, and keep it in proper order (syncing up with the current directory or thing at point etc.)
- And it may break in a future update of `helm`.

In short, no, unless you are prepared to do a fair bit of coding and then support it (or submit a pull request to `helm`.)